# What sci-fi movie had a cloud that turned things black with lightning?

Tags: story-identification

Back in 1997-1998, when I was 7-8 years old, I saw I think a sci-fi/horror movie. The movie was about a cloud that was attacking a village with lightning. The lightning turned everything it hit black - animals, humans, and I think rocks and houses.

The scene that I remember best was somewhere near the beginning. The people of the village have gathered and watched the cloud in fear, and all of a sudden the cloud hit one man with lightning and changed his skin from white to black. The man was all right — he was not fried, his skin just changed to black. And then all of the people started running from the cloud, even the man that was struck by lightning.

Comment: Was it a live action movie or a cartoon?